# biblatex: why isn't my own .bbx file found?

Tags: biblatex

In both the LaTeX source file's directory and in my local `texmf` tree (namely, in `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx`) I've placed the following `.bbx` file:

```
\ProvidesFile{mybooknumeric.bbx}
%[\abx@bbxid]
\RequireBibliographyStyle{standard}
\RequireBibliographyStyle{numeric}
%
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{dashed}[true]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{pagetracker}%
     \renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{\savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}}
    {\renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{}}}
%
\newbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{%
  \savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
```

The purpose of that is simply to used horizontal lines to replace the author name for subsequent bibliography entries having the same author.

But when I process my source, such as the one below, I get an error:

> (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
>   (./mybooknumeric.bbx
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx))
>
> /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty:13002: Packa
>   ge biblatex Error: Style 'mybooknumeric' not found.
>   ...
>
> l.13002 \RequireCitationStyle{\blx@cbxfile}

What's wrong?

The source:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[style=mybooknumeric,backend=bibtex,,dashed=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{euler.bib}
@article{EulerE1776,
    Author = {Euler, Leonhard},Title = {All about E},
    Journal = {Math.\ Psychol.},
    Year = {1776},Volume = {4},number={1},
    pages={1--2718}
}
@article{EulerE1748,
    Author = {Euler, Leonhard},Title = {My formula},
    Journal = {Math.\ Formulas},
    Year = {1748},Volume = {4},
    pages={233--234}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{euler.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is finding the `.bbx` from what you've shown. But you don't seem to have a corresponding `.cbx` file. Note that there are the options `style=`, `bibstyle=`, and `citestyle=` when it comes to `biblatex`.

Comment: @jon 's comment is correct. By using `style` instead of `bibstyle`, you tell `biblatex` to look for both a `.bbx` and `.cbx` file. Since you don't have the latter, you should use `bibstyle` instead. @jon you should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Among `biblatex`'s 'load-time' options are (`biblatex` version 3.5, §.3.1.1):

```
style=<file>                                             default: numeric 
Loads the bibliography style file .bbx and the citation style file .cbx.
See § 3.3 for an overview of the standard styles.

bibstyle=<file>                                           default: numeric
Loads the bibliography style file .bbx. See § 3.3.2 for an overview of the
standard bibliography styles.

citestyle=<file>                                          default: numeric
Loads the citation style file .cbx. See § 3.3.1 for an overview of the
standard citation styles.
```

So, if you use `style=mybooknumeric`, `biblatex` will try to find both `mybooknumeric.bbx` and `mybooknumeric.cbx`. In your case, it managed to find the former, but cannot (obviously) find the latter.

So you probably want to load `biblatex` in the following way:

```
% strictly speaking, naming the `citestyle` is not needed 
% if you want the 'numeric' style
\usepackage[bibstyle=mybooknumeric, citestyle=numeric, backend=bibtex, dashed=true]{biblatex}
```

... or create a `mybooknumeric.cbx`.

Comment: oops: I forgot about the `.cbx` vs. `.bbx` distinction. (I'm still overcoming my addiction to a single style name with plain `bibtex` instead of `biblatex`. Thanks!