# How can I use my custom style in LaTeX? - Part 2

Tags: biblatex

this is a follow up question to the question I asked yesterday that has been considered to be a "duplicate".

I created the directories mentioned here: [Where can I put biblatex style modifications?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40243/where-can-i-put-biblatex-style-modifications) 
and saved my bbx and cbx files in these directories.

LaTeX still won't find `style=mystyle`. 
I read this question: [biblatex: why isn't my own .bbx file found?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335950/biblatex-why-isnt-my-own-bbx-file-found?rq=1) but it doesn't help, I have both a `bbx` and `cbx` file.

What is wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: you also need define path that your latex can find them and also update data base for your latex installation. for this miktex has special wizard "miktex settings". for other latex distribution should be something similar, but i'm not familiar for them.

Comment: Thanks. Does anybody know how to do that using TeXLive and TeXStudio?

Comment: Are you on Linux or Mac? It should be enough to simply move the files to `~/texmf/biblatex/bbx` or thereabouts. Did you use `/texmf/` or `~/texmf/`? Where exactly did you move your files? What happens if you run `kpsewhich mystyle.bbx`?

Comment: You should use `TEXMFHOME` which is on Linux normally `~/texmf/`. If the folder is not there, you can simply create it.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-what-TDS.html and http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-privinst.html I suggest you go for `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` instead of `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a TeX live system. Having read http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-privinst.html and http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-what-TDS.html I have come to the conclusion that `TEXMFHOME` would be the best place to put your files in that case. The advantage of `TEXMFHOME` over other places is that you don't need to run `texhash` and that you almost definitely have full write access.

Use

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
```

to find out where `TEXMFHOME` is.

It most likely is `~/texmf`. If that directory does not exist, you will have to create it.

Then simply drop your `.bbx` and `.cbx` files into, say

```
~/texmf/biblatex/mystyle
```

and you are good to go.

People using MikTeX should refer to [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483/35864).